# How to get notified of all system package intents – regardless of whether my application is running or not when those intents are fired

Tags: android, android-intent

What I am trying to accomplish:

I am trying to keep track of all applications/packages installed/uninstalled/changed/replaced.  I would like to register my broadcast receiver to receiver all these intents and start a service to do my stuff. I would hope my broadcast receiver is invoked regardless of whether my app is currently active or not.

What I have done:

First I registered MyBroadcastReceiver for android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED,REMOVED,CHANGED,REPLACED intents in the manifest file. My receiver was not invoked. Looking through forum questions I came across this , suggesting to register the receiver dynamically for those intents, which I did in MyApplication.onCreate() override – but still with no success, not even when my application is active (possibly stopped).

What I am trying to avoid:

I would not want to use the ugliest and the inefficient approach to invoke the following code every time my application is started – just to sync with the system:

```
public List<ResolveInfo> getLaunchable() {
     Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
     intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);              
     return myContext.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
}
```

My question:

Could anybody please tell what I am missing in my solution? Is there a different solution to this issue?

My manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"     package="com.my_name_space" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />

<application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name">

    <receiver 
        android:name=".MyReceiver" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_CHANGED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
            <action android:name="com.gg.test_action"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

</application>

</manifest>
```

MyBroadcastReceiver:

```
package com.my_name_space;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // Never make it to here…
    Toast.makeText(context, "Got " + intent.getAction(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    }
}
```

In the dynamic registration variation I added PackageBrApp:

```
package com.my_name_space;
import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;

public class PackageBrApp extends Application { 
    public MyReceiver myReceiver = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();
        myReceiver = new MyReceiver();
        registerReceiver(myReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED));
        registerReceiver(myReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED));
        registerReceiver(myReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_CHANGED));
        registerReceiver(myReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED));
    }
}
```

and modified the manifest file accordingly (removed the receiver declaration):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android=http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android 
    package="com.gg" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name">
    </application>

</manifest>
```

## @@@@ Changes following the suggestion to add activity @@@@

Unfortunately adding an activity (and launching it not only after install and prior to first broadcast receiver usage, but multiple times) did not help.

The receiver still refuses to wake up…

Here is the updated receiver code (updating to some persistent preference to eliminate the possibility that the debugger does not stop there).

```
package com.my_name_space;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.util.Log;
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("ActivityBr", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);        
        Editor prefsEditor = prefs.edit();
        prefsEditor.putBoolean("receiverInvoked", true);
        prefsEditor.apply();        
    }
}
```

The added activity:

```
package com.my_name_space;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ActivityBr extends Activity  {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);               
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        TextView v = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view);

        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("ActivityBr", MODE_PRIVATE);
        boolean receiverInvoked = prefs.getBoolean("receiverInvoked", false);
        v.setText((receiverInvoked ? "BR invoked" : "BR not invoked"));

        Editor prefsEditor = prefs.edit();
        prefsEditor.putBoolean("receiverInvoked", false);
        prefsEditor.apply();
    }
}
```

and the manifest file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.my_name_space"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".ActivityBr"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver 
            android:name=".MyReceiver" 
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_CHANGED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
                <action android:name="com.gg.test_action"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

If it makes any difference the main.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/app_name" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Guess I am stuck with the ugly solution of periodic polling for changes...

Answer (score 1):

> First I registered MyBroadcastReceiver for android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED,REMOVED,CHANGED,REPLACED intents in the manifest file. My receiver was not invoked.

I am going to guess that you are testing this on an Android 3.1+ environment. If so, you need to have an activity in your app, and the user has to [run that activity manually once](http://commonsware.com/blog/2011/07/13/boot-completed-regression-confirmed.html) before your manifest-registered receivers will respond.

Comment: Many thanks! I actually have an activity (not listed in the very stripped down version of my code). I will check this again, and comment if it solved my problem. My current workaround to periodically (or on every main activity onStart()) poll the system is too ugly/inefficient.